# [HTML/PHP]: Do I need to change the extension of .html file 

Tags: php, html

If I create a simple .html file with a table inside it. Within one of the columns of a table, if I insert PHP opening and closing tags, and even just type echo, it is not working. Do I need to change the extension of the file to .php?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Changing the file to .php would be the quickest solution.

An alternate solution would be to use Apache's [addType](http://www.apacheref.com/ref/mod_mime/AddType.html) to allow apache to serve PHP pages with a different extension.

```
AddType application/x-httpd-php .html .htm
```

Answer (score 1):

Yes, in most cases.

Answer (score 0):

The webserver needs to know it has to process the file through the php processor, instead of just giving it to the user as is the default for a .html file. 
So renaming to .php is the easiest way to get that.

If you use AddType, then *all* html files are going through the php processor, which might slow things down too much.